# Pandas groupby select last row or second to last row based on value (0 or 1) in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with customers. Each customer has several observations and variables, and some are no longer a customer.

My question is the following:

I want to group by customer and select the last row if the customer is still a customer, and the second to last row if the customer is not a customer anymore.
I have a column named churned that is 1 if the customer has churned (no longer a customer), and 0 if it is still a customer, for all observations of the customer.

I know I can select the last row (-1) or second to last row (-2) as such: 
`df = df.groupby(['CustomerID'],as_index=False).nth(-1).reset_index()`

This also seem to work, although the order is different: 
`df = df.groupby(['CustomerID']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])`

I have been trying to use a if else statement in a lambda function like this: 
`df = df.groupby(['CustomerID'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2] if x['churned']==1 else x.iloc[-1]).reset_index()`

But I get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there any way I can group by CustomerID, condition on the column churned and get only the last row of the customers where churned==0, and the second to last row if churned==1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `x['churned']==1` for all rows in the group. To check if it presents in the group you have to use `any()`:

```
df = df.groupby(['CustomerID'],as_index=False).apply \
    (lambda x: x.iloc[-2] if (x['churned']==1).any() \
    else x.iloc[-1]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work, although I am unsure why the customers is in a different order than in the original df.

Comment: @Preben Check if the index goes sequentially, if not, do `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: No matter what I do, apply changes the order of the customers in the same way for some reason. I would have thought it would just keep the last or second to last row per customer starting from the top. The first 20 rows are one customer over time, then the next 10 might be another etc. It is not a huge issue, I just found it weird and don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide them into two dataframes - customers and non-customers, and use the last() function:

```
df.groupby(['CustomerID'],as_index=False).last()
```